# Creating a stacked tiff file causes image offset

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, imagej

I have a an image processing program whose results need to be saved to a stacked tiff file. The code for the method that does this is included below. When the resulting image is opened in ImageJ it gives the notification "Unexpected image offset" and only can display the first image in the stack.
fig = figure;
figure(fig);

```
fileN = handles.fileName;
[m n] = size(fileN);
m = 0;
for i=1:n
    if(fileN(i) == '.')
        m = i;
        break
    end
end
fileN = fileN(:,1:m-1);
fileP = handles.filePath;
saveFilePath = strcat(fileP,fileN,'-snake-analysis.tif')

im = imread(handles.fileFull, 1);
imshow(im, []);
hold on
plot(handles.xsFinal(1,:), handles.ysFinal(1,:), 'r-');
hold off
saveas(fig, saveFilePath);

for i=2:handles.numFrames
    im = imread(handles.fileFull, i);
    imshow(im, []);
    hold on
    plot(handles.xsFinal(i,:), handles.ysFinal(i,:), 'r-');
    hold off

    saveas(fig, 'inter.tif');
    a = imread('inter.tif');
    imwrite(a, saveFilePath,'Compression', 'none','WriteMode','append');
    delete 'inter.tif';
end
```

Does anyone know what is causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The built-in ImageJ 1.x TIFF opener does not fully handle the baseline TIFF specification: it [cannot handle out-of-sequence planes](https://github.com/imagej/ImageJA/blob/v1.50d/src/main/java/ij/io/Opener.java#L755-L760).

If you use [ImageJ2](http://imagej.net/ImageJ2), you can use the [SCIFIO](http://imagej.net/SCIFIO) library to open your TIFF via the File ▶ Import ▶ Image... command. The [Bio-Formats Importer plugin](http://imagej.net/Bio-Formats) can also open such TIFF files.